# Why does startActivity work in one method and fail in another?

Tags: android

I am an android beginner.

I'm struggling to understand why startActivity runs properly when copied from a tutorial I found and fails when I make the smallest change.

**Code from the tutorial:**

```
private class ButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleButtonClick();
    }   
}

private void handleButtonClick() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondAct.class));
}
```

That works.  When I try to change it to what I would consider a simpler design, I am getting an error.

```
private class ButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondAct.class));
    }   
}
```

**The error is:**

> The constructor Intent(FirstTwoApps.ButtonHandler, Class)
>   is undefined

Notice that all I did was moved the action from the `handleButtonClick()` method to the `onClick()` method.  Apparently that is not allowed, but I don't understand why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `this` reference to that of the enclosing class, i.e. if your class is named `Main`, change it to `Main.this`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even know you could do that in Java until I started working with Android. +1

Answer (score 1):

Because `startActivity` is a method of `Context`. In the first example, it is being run from a `Context` object, in the second it is being run from a `ButtonHandler` object. This is a scoping problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This helps me understand why the error is happening, which will help me troubleshoot similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, **handleButtonClick()** exists within your Activity class which has context reference to start **startActivity()** by **this**.

Now, **onClick()** exists in ButtonHandler class which has no context scope at all.

So to get context reference from ButtonHandler class you must have to use **YouarActivity.this** instead **this**.

**Solution** -

```
private class ButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(YouarActivity.this, SecondAct.class));
    }   
}
```